# TTYs are not working with ppa nvidia-current driver on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, tty

Mar 18

---

I bought a new Dell 660s for learning Linux! It is Intel i3, 4 GB, 500Gb HD, 23" dell led display and a nVIDIA GT 620 video card. I chose Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64. It is freshly installed.

I added a PPA source (see https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) and installed the package **nvidia-current** and then rebooted.

The video card works on 1024x768, instead of native 1920x1080. Only resolutions of 1024x768 and 800x600 can be chosen in the system settings. Even worse, when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>, all the ttys are blank. In fact, I tryed many times and read many texts online. All I can do now is to try to ask here for help.
[image]

Mar 19

---

I changed driver from ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates to ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa (see https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa). And installed the post-release one.
[image: driver]

Now desktop display resolution is better. And now, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>, **the screen is not that blank but changed to a black screen with only a blinking prompt as '_'. The TTY is not working still.**
[image: Dell 23"]

Answer (score 0):

To get the very latest Xorg and nvidia driver for Ubuntu 12.04, you should install [the X-edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

*Please go to their page and read their disclaimer.*

However, I do use this PPA in production on AMD and nVidia workstations and latops, and it's working well.

Comment: You should not put the instructions on how to add their PPA directly on on ask Ubuntu. X-Edgers asks clearly that you should point to their page, because they want to be sure that users read their disclaimers!!!